# CiviCRM cron doesn't trigger all tasks

Tags: civimail, cron-job

On a Wordpress install I'm having problems with the main cron job. We're using Civihosting, so the cron job has been set up as a shell script that is fired every 15 minutes. The cron job is working on schedule as I've set it to notify me via email every time it runs.

I have a number of scheduled jobs set up within CiviCRM to fire every time the cron job runs. Looking at the log the only one of these that is getting triggered is the fetch_bounces job. So at least I can see that the cron task is doing something. The process_mailing job however is not getting triggered, despite being set up to run 'Always'.

Is this a known issue with version 4.6.2.? I'm about to update to 4.6.5 hoping that might fix this.

Comment: I think the most important step in troubleshooting is to run the command that cron is running manually (as the same user cron uses, ideally), and look for output.  My guess is you'll see some fatal error on some job that's preventing other jobs from running.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your bounce and/or email-to-activity inboxes. We had [this bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17438) where UTF-8 in the display name caused the whole cron run to repeatedly crash, and cron would not run until I moved the offending message.

Answer (score 0):

These are  related: [Cron job fatal error - scheduled emails won't send. AddThis 5.0.7 issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/cron-job-fatal-error-scheduled-emails-wont-send-addthis-5-0-7-issue/3790#3790) and [Cron job fatal error - scheduled emails won't send. AddThis 5.0.7 issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/cron-job-fatal-error-scheduled-emails-wont-send-addthis-5-0-7-issue/3790#3790)

I have found that with WordPress the best way is to use wp-cli and the best way to configure that is to use SSH.  To be